# Undefined reference to operator << in inherited class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the << and >> operators for a polygon class and a derived triangle class. The problem is that my compiler is returning the following error:

```
error: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, triangle const&)'
```

I am fairly certain that I did define the above operator however. I have the following line in my triangle.h file:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, triangle const&);
```

This problem occurs specifically for the triangle class. When I remove the line trying to output a triangle, my program works correctly. There is no problem outputting a polygon. What is causing this problem and how do I fix it? Is it a problem with my include hierarchy?

I think the relevant files are main.cpp, triangle.h, and triangle.cpp but I included a full copy of my code below in case the error is caused by something else. Thank you for your help and patience.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "triangle.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    triangle t (vertex (0, 0), vertex (5, 0), vertex (0, 5));
    triangle l (t);

    cout << l[0] << endl;
    cout << "L: " << l << endl; //not working

    polygon p;
    p.add (vertex (0,0));
    cout << "P: " << p << endl; //working
    return 0;
}
```

triangle.h

```
#include "polygon.h"
#include <iostream>

class triangle : public polygon
{
public:
    triangle(vertex = vertex(), vertex = vertex(), vertex = vertex());

    triangle(const triangle &);

    double area() const;

    vertex operator[](size_t i) const;

private:
    size_t size() const;
    void add(vertex iv);
    std::vector<vertex> v;
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, triangle const&);
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, triangle & t);
```

triangle.cpp

```
#include "triangle.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <cassert>


triangle::triangle(vertex ta, vertex tb, vertex tc)
{
    v.push_back(ta);
    v.push_back(tb);
    v.push_back(tc);
}

triangle::triangle(const triangle & t)
{
    v=t.v;
}

double triangle::area() const
{
    double a=sqrt((v[0].x-v[1].x)*(v[0].x-v[1].x)+(v[0].y-v[1].y)*(v[0].y-v[1].y));
    double b=sqrt((v[1].x-v[2].x)*(v[1].x-v[2].x)+(v[1].y-v[2].y)*(v[1].y-v[2].y));
    double c=sqrt((v[2].x-v[0].x)*(v[2].x-v[0].x)+(v[2].y-v[0].y)*(v[2].y-v[0].y));
    double s=((a+b+c)/2);
    return sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));
}

vertex triangle::operator[] (std::size_t i) const
{
    assert (i<3);
    return v[i];
}

inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, triangle const & t)
{
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    return os << t[0];
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, triangle & t)
{
    vertex vx;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        is >> vx.x >> vx.y;
        //t.v.push_back(vx);
    }
    return is;
}
```

polygon.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "vertex.h"

class polygon

{
    public:
    // pre:
    // post: empty polygon created
    polygon();

    // pre:
    // post: polygon created and initialized to given polygon source
    polygon(const polygon & source);

    // pre:
    // post: return number of vertices in this polygon
    std::size_t size() const;

    // pre: 0 <= i < size()
    // post: return vertex i in this polygon
    vertex operator[](size_t i) const;

    // pre:
    // post: vertex is added to this polygon
    void add(const vertex & v);

    private:

    std::vector<vertex> v;

};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const polygon & p);
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, polygon & p);
```

polygon.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include "polygon.h"

polygon::polygon()
{
    v = std::vector<vertex> ();
}

polygon::polygon(const polygon & p)
{
    v = p.v;
}

std::size_t polygon::size() const
{
    return v.size();
}

vertex polygon::operator[] (std::size_t i) const
{
    assert(i < size());
    return v[i];
}

void polygon::add(const vertex & vx)
{
    v.push_back(vx);
}

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const polygon & p)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
        os << p[i] << " ";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, polygon & p)
{
    std::size_t n;
    vertex vx;

    is >> n;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        is >> vx.x >> vx.y;
        p.add(vx);
    }
    return is;
}
```

vertex.h

```
#include <iostream>

struct vertex
{
    double x, y;

    vertex(double ix = 0.0, double iy = 0.0)
    {
        x = ix;
        y = iy;
    }
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const vertex & v);
```

vertex.cpp

```
#include "vertex.h"

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const vertex & v)
{
    os << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: An "undefined reference" error sounds like you aren't linking in `triangle.o` or `triangle.obj` (depends on your platform).

Comment: @Matt Yes, I initially used 'const triangle' but I edited my code to match the compiler error exactly to see if that would fix the problem. Both versions do not currently work.

Comment: This is a linking problem.  What does your makefile look like?  Or, is your triangle.cpp file included in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
// triangle.cpp
inline std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, triangle const & t)
^^^^^^
```

Inline functions must be defined in all translation units that use them, and this is only defined in one. Either remove `inline`, or move the definition into the header to make it available anywhere its used.

Comment: +1 Confirmed. I was getting the OP's error message before making this change, and compiled successfully after deleting `inline`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. The weird thing is, I added that 'inline' as an attempt to fix another error related to that function but everything seems to work smoothly once I remove it.